# Full sized images on Wikipedia fail to load - blocked by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

Tags: browser

When I click on a thumbnail in a Wikipedia article to view the image in a larger size I am presented with an error of this type:

> Error: Could not load thumbnail data. could not load image from
>   http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ce/9_dotted_line.png/320px-9_dotted_line.png

[image: wikipedia thumbnail error]

Upon viewing the browser console I see errors such as this:

> Image from origin 'http://upload.wikimedia.org' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://en.wikipedia.org' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Thus this looks like an issue with Wikipedia(/media)'s server config. What is the cause of these errors and is there a way to solve it from the client side?

Comment: Which browser are you using? This sounds like some too strict security setting.

Comment: The problem occurs in both Chrome and Firefox, but strangely not in IE